# Magento 1.9.3.4 PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function refund() on null

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error, refund, magento-1.9.3.4

When I am about to issue a credit/refund, I go to the Invoice > Credit Memo and try to > Refund Online, then I receive a fatal error 500.

Looking in error_log this is the record:

```
  PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function refund() on null in 
 /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php on line 693
```

Here is the code in question from that file: (starting from line 680-703)

```
    if ($gateway->canRefund() && $creditmemo->getDoTransaction()) {
        $this->setCreditmemo($creditmemo);
        $invoice = $creditmemo->getInvoice();
        if ($invoice) {
            $isOnline = true;
            $captureTxn = $this->_lookupTransaction($invoice->getTransactionId());
            if ($captureTxn) {
                $this->setParentTransactionId($captureTxn->getTxnId());
            }
            $this->setShouldCloseParentTransaction(true); // TODO: implement multiple refunds per capture
            try {
                $gateway->setStore($this->getOrder()->getStoreId())
                    ->processBeforeRefund($invoice, $this)
                    ->refund($this, $baseAmountToRefund)  //LINE 693 joell
                    ->processCreditmemo($creditmemo, $this)
                ;
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                if (!$captureTxn) {
                    $e->setMessage(' ' . Mage::helper('sales')->__('If the invoice was created offline, try creating an offline creditmemo.'), true);
                }
                throw $e;
            }
        }
    }
```

Appreciate any input

Answer (score 0):

After further testing and digging, we found the issue is only with Stripe payment method.
We used the free netgo_stripe module which caused the error.

Authorize net works smooth with no issues.